# After scroll down button for go to the top of the website will show smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my scrool to top button. I set that the button will show after I scroll down 200px but i don´t know how to set that button will show smoothly or how to animate it. Can you help me?

Thank you.

```js
let mybutton = document.getElementById("btnScrollToTop");

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
const btnScrollToTop = document.querySelector("#btnScrollToTop");
btnScrollToTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
});
```

```css
#btnScrollToTop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#btnScrollToTop:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ffb038;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnScrollToTop">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that by changing the `button`'s `display` property as that property [is **NOT** animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_definition).

A quick alternative to the `display` property, and that can be animatable, is to use the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property. Let's say we'll have a nice `fade in` and `fade out` effects on the `button` when that later appears and disappears respectively.

To do so, we'll need to use the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) property along with the `visibility` property:

- Initially, the button is hidden using `visibility: hidden` rule and also to have a fade in/out effect we'll initially apply `opacity: 0` rule as well so the button can fade in smoothly when we want to.
- Once the page scrolls after `200px` we'll programmatically fade in the button  by applying an `opacity` of `1` (`opacity: 1`) and also to set the `visibility` property to `visible` so our fade effect can run smoothly as we want.
- Lastly, when we need to hide the button like when we're at the top of the page, we'll revert the `visibility` and the `opacity` properties to `hidden` and `0` respectively so we get a nice fade out effect.

To optimize things a bit, we'll declare a new `CSS` class, let's call it `visible`, that we apply to the `button` when we need it to fade in and remove it (the class) when we want the `button` to fade out. With that class we only need to apply it or remove it from the button and we no longer need to change the `button`'s styles manually on the `JavaScript` part.

Here's a quick demo, try to scroll down a bit and you'll see the fade in effect on the `button` and try to click it or manually scroll back up to see the fade out effect:

```js
const toTopBtn = document.getElementById('btnScrollToTop'),
  scrollFunction = () => toTopBtn.classList[document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200 ? 'add' : 'remove']('visible');

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);

toTopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
}));
```

```css
/* only to showcase the hide/show on the button we add some scrolling region to the page */

body {
  height: 300vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#btnScrollToTop {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* initially hidden */
  opacity: 0;
  /* initially set to "0" opacity */
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
  /* needed to have a nice fade in/out transitions */
}

#btnScrollToTop:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ffb038;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


/* our new class that will allow the fade in/out effect */

#btnScrollToTop.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnScrollToTop">Top</button>
```